# Is it necessary to always use mutator methods to reassign a field?

Tags: java, security, exception

I am trying to write this code as properly as possible, and I'm not sure if catching the *NumberOutOFBoundsException* is necessary for something like this.

```
public Car(String make, String model, String year, int topSpeed, int fuelCapacity, int milesPerGallon) throws NumberOutOfBoundsException{
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
  this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
  this.fuelCapacity = fuelCapacity;
  this.milesPerGallon = milesPerGallon;

  try{
     setSpeed(0);
     setMileage(0);
     setFuel(0);
  }catch(NumberOutOfBoundsException ex){
     throw ex;
  }
}
```

Here is another example:

```
//this method will attempt to simulate traveling in a car
//given the time traveled, mileage and remaining fuel should be affected
//if there is not enough fuel, then this method will fail
public void travel(int hours) throws NumberOutOfBoundsException{
  //save rollback values
  double fuel = getFuel();
  int mileage = getMileage();
  int miles = speed * hours;
  double fuelUsage = calculateFuelUsage(miles, milesPerGallon);
  //line 7
  try{

     move(miles);
  }catch(NumberOutOfBoundsException ex){
     try{
        setFuel(fuel);
        setMileage(mileage);
        throw ex;
     }catch(NumberOutOfBoundsException ex1){
        throw ex1;
     }
  }
}
```

and an example of one of my mutators:

```
public void setSpeed(int speed) throws NumberOutOfBoundsException{
  if(speed > topSpeed || speed < 0)
     throw new NumberOutOfBoundsException();

  this.speed = speed;
}
```

For `travel()`, I believe the nested try-catch may or may not be redundant.

The reason why I think this may be necessary is for security reasons. If I just set the field *fuel* to the rollback value without calling `setFuel(fuel)` (line 13), what if a hacker paused my code in `travel()` on line 7, then changed the value of *hours* to force the exception to be caught, and then changed the value of the local *fuel* to give himself as much fuel as he wanted? Am I thinking about it too much, or would this be an actual security issue?

Comment: What a `NumberOutOFBoundsException`? Is that a custom type?

Comment: If a hacker has access to your live code, all bets are off. Is this server code or a desktop app?

Comment: NumberOutOfBoundsException is custom. It simply extends Exception.

Comment: you either `throw` it or you `catch` it, you don't do both at a time.

Comment: This is a desktop app, but It is for educational purposes, so it could be server code as well.

Comment: I threw it in the catch statement to pass it to the calling method.

Comment: If it's a desktop app, a hacker could whatever he wants by decompiling/recompiling/debugging your code. If it's a server app, you better hope a hacker has no way to pause your code or change anything. The bottom line is you're focused on the wrong problem. Defensive programming is more about protecting your code from legitimate users and developers (including yourself).

Comment: I understand. Thank you!